#  java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access > Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: java, jsp

I'm calling `InserStudent.jsp` file in action of the form from `AddStudent.jsp`
from where I want to insert the data in database.

My database table's structure is below:

```
ID|Name|RollNumber|PhoneNumber|StudyProgram|Status
```

Below is the code for `InserStudent.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<body>

    <%
     String nam=request.getParameter("stuname");  
     String roll=request.getParameter("sturoll");  
     String phone=request.getParameter("stuphone");  
     String prog=request.getParameter("stuprogram");  
     String stats=request.getParameter("stustatus");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url =  "jdbc:odbc:stdProjectDataDSN";
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement statement = c.createStatement() ;
String sql = "insert into students (ID, NAME, RollNumber, PhoneNumber, StudyProgram, Status )";
sql += "values ( '"+ nam +"','"+ nam +"','"+ roll +"','"+ phone +"','"+ prog +"',"+ stats +" )";
statement.execute ( sql );
c.close();
response.sendRedirect("ManageAllStudent.jsp");
    %>
 </body>
</html>
```

This results in the following exception:

> **HTTP Status 500**
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /web/InserStudent.jsp at line 27
>
> 24: Statement statement = c.createStatement() ;
>   25: String sql = "insert into students (ID, NAME, RollNumber, PhoneNumber, StudyProgram, Status )";
>   26: sql += "values ( '"+ nam +"','"+ nam +"','"+ roll +"','"+ phone +"','"+ prog +"',"+ stats +" )";
>
> 27: statement.execute ( sql );
>   28:    c.close(); 
>   29: 
>   30:        response.sendRedirect("ManageAllStudent.jsp");
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access > Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong? In `ShowAllStudent.jsp` page it shows me all the data from database where I use the same script.

Comment: also edit the below code for **Class.forName** but it also does'not work

`Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what iam missing i didnot configure my database in control panel->administrative tools...

So when i set it up it just work:)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write Java code in `JSP` (Read SO FAQ - [How to avoid Java Code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/142822)). You must have to add `Servlet` to perform database operations.

Apart from this you have to learn how JDBC API works and as @BalusC commented that your code is victim of sql injection vulnerability. To avoid SQL injection, use the PrepreadStatement (parameterized query).

```
Connection cn=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url =  "jdbc:odbc:stdProjectDataDSN";
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

try{
  String sql="insert into students (ID,NAME,RollNumber,PhoneNumber,StudyProgram,Status) 
               Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setInt(1,10);
  ps.setString(2,nam);
  ...
  ps.executeUpdate()
}catch(SQLException ex){

}finally{
  if(ps!=null){
     try { ps.close(); } catch(Exception ex) {}
  }
  if(cn!=null){
     try { cn.close(); } catch(Exception ex) {}
  }
}
```

PS: In case the column `ID` is autogenerate number then do not include in your column set.

```
 String sql="insert into students (NAME,RollNumber,PhoneNumber,StudyProgram,Status) 
                   Values (?,?,?,?,?)";
```